# What is the best way to differentiate between columns with words and those with letters and numbers using REGEXP?

Tags: sql

I have below 2 tables for header and trailer.

1. Header_table
2. Trailer_Table

The first row containing strings (Res state Inc) has to go inside header table and the second row containing alphabet and numbers has to go inside trailer table (1075AB).

Table name: Record_table

| Record |
| --- |
| Res state Inc |
| 1075AB |

Will the below would be a right approach ?

```
select * from record_table where record REGEXP '.*[a-z];--header
select * from record_table where record REGEXP '.*[^a-z];--trailer
```

Comment: Mysql and snowflake are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: Im using snowflake